ggboxplot error bars: what are they errors of?
I am using ggboxplot for some data I am graphing. Part of my code is below (I have not added all of it because it is complicated with the visual additions):
ggboxplot(AllLiveNaiveFIULearnedPanamaAnalysisNoOutliers, x = "Group", y = "Seconds_Fixed", fill = "grey40", ylab = " Time (seconds)", xlab = "Quadrant",
          color = "Type", ylim = c(0, 6500))

Here is the graph it gives me:

When I graph this data, I get the boxes and the whiskers, which to my understanding by default is the quartiles. I want these lines to be error bars instead. To my understanding I can use the bxp.errorbar = TRUE to do this, so the part of my code I included above would look like this:
ggboxplot(AllLiveNaiveFIULearnedPanamaAnalysisNoOutliers, x = "Group", y = "Seconds_Fixed", fill = "grey40", ylab = " Time (seconds)", xlab = "Quadrant",
          color = "Type", ylim = c(0, 6500), bxp.errorbar = TRUE)

When I graph it, it basically just adds the an extra width line:

What are these error bars? Are they confidence intervals, standard deviations, standard errors, something else, etc?
Also, if this isn't standard deviation, say I want to add standard deviation bars to my graph: how would I do so?
